# Why doesn't ReSharper natively support Xunit with the test runner?

Tags: resharper, xunit

I can see that there is a Xunit.Contrib plugin, but why doesn't R# natively support running tests within VS that are written with Xunit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question can be asked about any unit testing framework (or, indeed, any technology) that isn't currently supported natively in ReSharper. The answer is mostly concerned with time and resource constraints, as well as the fact that the original creators of the unit test framework are often in a much better position to provide support, having a much better understanding of how things work.